# Assignment to variable in indent

Tags: python

Very simple problem (At least I think so): So I have a global variable, in this case `test`, and I want to assign an other value to it in a function. This is my code:

```
test = "Hello"

def launch():
    test = "F"

launch()
print(test)
```

I wanted `test` to equal "F", but it doesn't. Instead, the output of this is that `test` still equals "Hello". I assume it creates a variable inside the function and then assigns a value to it. 
But why does this work then:

```
test = {
    "?": "Hallo"
}

def launch():
    test["?"] = "F"

launch()
print(test)
```

The output of this is how I wanted it to be: `test["?"]` is equal to "F". 
How is this working and why isn't the first code example?
Is there any way to use the first code how I wanted it to work?

Comment: In the first case, you're trying to access a global variable but you have also redeclared it as a local variable. In second case,you're assigning to a global variable, not redeclaring it as a local variable. There in lies the difference.

Comment: Check this tutorial for more examples https://www.python-course.eu/python3_global_vs_local_variables.php

Comment: This actually has to do with the mutability of objects in Python. In the first case, the object test is immutable, so changes to `test` in your function creates a new local object. In the second case, the dictionary `test` is a mutable object, so alterations to it within a function stick.

Comment: @CaitLANJenner I don't think this has anything to do with mutability of the object. It likely has more to do with the fact that `test["?"] = "F"` is equivalent to `test.__setItem__("?", "F")`, and that only makes sense if `test` already exists. I would expect the same behavior in the first case even if `test` was mutable. Unless you're talking about reassignment vs mutation of the object.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using global variables in a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python, variables that are only *referenced* inside a function are implicitly global. If a variable is *assigned* a value anywhere within the function’s body, however, it’s assumed to be a local unless explicitly declared as global.

So, change it as follows:

```
test = "Hello"

def launch():
    global test
    test = "F"
```

Comment: With the exception of mutable objects. In the second example the `test` dictionary is mutable and thus alterations to it do not result in creating a new object and the changes hold globally.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a `global test` line to the top of the function to tell it to reference an existing variable instead of creating a new one. It's ambiguous otherwise.

---

Why does the second one work though? Because it isn't ambiguous. From context, it knows that you must be referencing an existing variable instead of attempting to create a new one.

```
test["?"] = "F"
```

is essentially

```
test.__setItem__("?", "F")
```

and that only makes sense if `test` already exists. It knows that you aren't trying to create a new local variable.

The language only requires a `global test` statement in cases where it can't tell whether or not you want to use an existing variable or create a new one.

Answer (score 0):

In your second example you don't declare the dictionary (like `test = {}`). Hence, python looks for a global variable `test`. You can access global variables by:

```
def launch():
    global test
    test = "F"
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first case, you're trying to access a global variable but you have also redeclared it as a local variable.

```py
test = "Hello" #global variable by default.

def launch():
    test = "F" # local variable by default. It's restricted to the function launch().

launch()
print(test) # Accessing global variable because print can't see test of launch.
```

```py
test = "Hello" #global variable by default.

def launch():
    global test
    test = "F" # Accessing global value of test.

launch()
print(test) # Accessing global variable test.
```

In second case,you're assigning to a global variable, not redeclaring it as a local variable. There in lies the difference.

```py
test = {'?':"Hello"} #global variable by default.

def launch():
    test['?'] = "F" # global variable access by default. It's NOT restricted to the function launch().

launch()
print(test) # Accessing global variable.
```

Answer (score 0):

In your first test, in your launch function, the `test` variable is recreated, with no link to the global function. It's a particularity of python.

If you wanted to change the global function you should have done like this :

```
def launch():
   global test
   test = 'F'
```

With your second test, `test` is a dictionary.

And yes, when you change a dictionary in a function without declaring it as a global variable, it changes the dictionary outside of the function as well.

If you want to know the real reason, it's way more complicated if you don't know C language... Python was programmed in C (for CPython at least), and in C, managing variables is very different than in Python.

In C, when you want to modify a variable in a function, you have to give to the function the memory address of the variable as a parameter (that variable is called a Pointer).

If you don't give the pointer of your global variable to the function where you want to modify it, it won't work.

When your `launch` function was called in your first example, test wasn't modified, because as you haven't declared `test` as global, python hasn't given the pointer of `test` to the `launch` function (only its value).

When you use dictionaries, Python will also give the value of the dictionary, but it will be a pointer to its elements. So you will be able to modify them.

That's why you can modify the elements in the dictionary, but you can't modify the dictionary. Example :

```
a = {"a":123, 'b':456}
def modif():
    a = {"aa":123}
modif()
print(a)
```

results in:

```
{'a': 123, 'b': 456}
```

So the dictionary hasn't been modified. It works the same way with the lists (and I suppose with every iterable that support item assignment)

I tried to simplify, it's more complicated in reality, but it may teach you some thing I hope.